# system.profile.find() command returns no results

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm trying to run queries against MongoDB (in Ubuntu) and analyse the execution times. I think i've set the profiler up correctly, but when I run a query against it, i'm not getting any response whatsoever.

Clearly i'm missing something. The code below shows the DB i've created, inserted a single document, run a count against the DB, and then tried to access the profiler stats:

```
> db.setProfilingLevel(2)
{ "was" : 0, "slowms" : 100, "ok" : 1 }
> use products
switched to db products
> db.products.count();
0
> book1={"isbn":"456"}
{ "isbn" : "456" }
> db.products.insert(book1);
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.products.count();
1
> db.products.system.profile.find();
>
```

Can anyone advise where i'm going wrong?

Thanks for your help.
R,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out, the syntax was wrong in the command line.
Used the following which returned the report:

```
> db.system.profile.find()
```